# CS50 dna.py compare STR counts with database

Tags: python, cs50

So I got this far:

1. **names[]** - is a dict with CSV data
2. **str[]** - column names from CSV - to access STR names
3. **sequence[]** - dna sequence from TXT
4. **checked_seq[]** - list with STR counts from sequence

I now got stuck on the final task:

- Need to compare the STR counts against each person`s data from CSV
- Output the match

Here`s my code:

```
    # Read database file into a variable
    names = []
    # Read data from the file
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
        # Loop through the names
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for name in reader:
            names.append(name)

    # Read STRs
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline='') as file:
        readstr = csv.reader(file)
        rows = list(readstr)
        str = rows[0]


    # Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    sequence = []
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as file:
        sequence = file.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    checked_seq = []
    for i in range(len(str)):
        subsequence = str[i]
        reps = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)
        checked_seq.append(reps)
```

I was printing every data structure created along the lines and it looks like the STR count works.

Now here was my train of thought for the last task:

```
    for i in range(1, len(str) - 1):
        match = 0
        while True:
            if checked_seq[i] == names[i - 1][str[i]]:
                match += 1
            else:
                break
        if match == len(str) - 1:
            print(names[i - 1][str[0]])
        else:
            print("No match")
```

I was going to run a loop through every person's data and compare STR counts to STR counts from the checked TXT file. Every time there's a match I have to check the next STR for the same person and break out if it`s a no match or increment match count by one if STRs matched again.

I will check **match** count against **number of STRs** and if these values are the same then print out that person`s name.

Can someone please give me a clue where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Slept on it and found the solution that works.

**Problem solved!**